# Import data in json to mongo container docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a question. I'm starting learn docker. I know how create a container, now I try import data(json) to my container mongo, but I don't know how I can make this. Can you help me and give a simple solution for this? With Docker-compose.

My container - mongo
My file - data.json

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not import JSON simply using docker-compose. you need to place the data in js file and mount the `js` file with `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
>   with extensions `.sh` and `.js` that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. `.js` files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the `.js` script.

[mongo Initializing a fresh instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

Example js file:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("test");
db.article.drop();

db.article.save( {
    title : "this is my title" , 
    author : "bob" , 
    posted : new Date(1079895594000) , 
    pageViews : 5 , 
    tags : [ "fun" , "good" , "fun" ] ,
    comments : [ 
        { author :"joe" , text : "this is cool" } , 
        { author :"sam" , text : "this is bad" } 
    ],
    other : { foo : 5 }
});

db.article.save( {
    title : "this is your title" , 
    author : "dave" , 
    posted : new Date(4121381470000) , 
    pageViews : 7 , 
    tags : [ "fun" , "nasty" ] ,
    comments : [ 
        { author :"barbara" , text : "this is interesting" } , 
        { author :"jenny" , text : "i like to play pinball", votes: 10 } 
    ],
    other : { bar : 14 }
});

db.article.save( {
    title : "this is some other title" , 
    author : "jane" , 
    posted : new Date(978239834000) , 
    pageViews : 6 , 
    tags : [ "nasty" , "filthy" ] ,
    comments : [ 
        { author :"will" , text : "i don't like the color" } , 
        { author :"jenny" , text : "can i get that in green?" } 
    ],
    other : { bar : 14 }
});
```

docker-compose

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo1
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: test
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
    volumes:    
      - ./init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Comment: I will not recommend docker-commit, better to copy the js file to docker build to  `COPY init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`,